# Android equivalent for BlackBerry navigator invoke()

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

I'm testing an app created in android but on my blackberry playbook, and i have an action not supported error caused by this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("appworld://content/xxxxxx"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I read that to use the appworldId uri on native sdk, we use the navigator invoke method but how do I do it on android?

Comment: which blackberry os version is this for?

Comment: 2.1.0.1526 , any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will sound odd to you, but try changing the URI from

`"appworld://content/xxxxxx"`

to

`"market://details?id=xxxxxx"`

Where "xxxxxx" is NOT the AppWorld ID, but the package name (same as in Android).

Comment: ok now the app dont crash but instead of send me to my other app the link send me to the appworld store, like if never see my appworld ID

Comment: Well if it were for android, the xxxxxx would have been the package name. Try that.

Comment: thanks again I will try it later and then i will tell you if it work : )

Comment: it work!, i cant believe it was that easy, thanks you so much for your help : )